SSIS - Help for integrating external dll
I am planning to rebuild legacy SSIS projects and, in the new version, I have integrated ScriptTask type components in order to overcome some limitations of the framework.
Some of these scripts simply execute the contained C# code, others refer to an external library I wrote (version 1.0.0.0) and integrated into the system (Reference). I have also included it in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). The project, thus constructed, works.
I then tried updating the version of our library by changing only the value of AssemblyVersion(“2.0.0.0”) in the AssemblyInfo.cs file included in the library.
Once I performed the deletion from the GAC of version 1.0.0.0 and installed in the new 2.0.0.0, all ScriptTasks in the dtsx packages failed due to lack of reference to the external DLL. We tried the rebuild of the whole SSIS project, but without success.
How can I rebuild the entire SSIS project by making sure that the external dll references declared into ScriptTask components are updated?
I am developing with this setup:

Visual Studio 2022
SQL Server 2022
.NET Framework 4.7


a good solution could be right-click on the solution and press "rebuild". This operation should remove the old references and replace them with the new ones

The solution doesn't work. Can anyone help?
